# Import UML files into Papyrus

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

i have a problem with import uml files into the Eclipse modelling tool papyrus.
I can drag and drop the file into Papyrus. 
If i double click on it, i shows me the objects of the uml diagramm but i cant create a view/diagram.
I speed hours to find a solution in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Open Papyrus perspective.
You should be able to see Model in Model Explorer view.
Just check whether you can see the UML elements in this view. If you can then drag and drop it in the editor. Yous should be able to see the diagrams.